# How to paint directly on the UV image

Tags: texture-painting

Where is the option to paint directly on the UV image? i tried ''image editor'' and it only lets me sample colors but all the other tools are gone

[image]

Comment: Have you selected "Paint" mode for the Image Editor? (right next to the marked icon in the top left corner) => https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVrDl.png

Comment: As @Blunder suggested, make sure you have switched to _Paint_ mode... it looks like you're in _View_ mode. But it would have helped if you made a screenshot without the window being obstructed by the editor selection menu.